# java garbage collection about ZGC and G1

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc, zgc

What is the difference between ZGC's relocation set and G1' s collection set in Java？I and learning JAVA's garbage collection and feel uncertain about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collection Set` are the regions that `G1` considers to look further at. `G1`, in the `mark` phase, will compute some metadata about each region, one of those metadata information is how much is alive in each of them. It also knows how much time it took on the previous run to reclaim dead objects in each region. To meet it's goals of timeouts, it selects the regions with the *most* garbage and processes them. Those regions are called: `collection set`.

`Relocation Set` is basically the same thing, at least logically. `ZGC` selects regions (they call them `pages`) with *most* garbage. It first, under a stop-the-world event, relocates GC roots, and then, concurrently traverses this `Relocation Set`.

So in essence these are close to the same thing *logically*, since these GC are doing things quite differently, that is the bound where their similarities should be drawn, IMO.